# Disable blinking at the first/last line of the file

Tags: vim

So for me this is very annoying

I am at the first/last line of the file and when I hit k/j all text screen blinks. I know this is stupid but it is possible to disable this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To disable visual bell completely: `set t_vb=` in vimrc or gvimrc (if you use gvim, you must put it into gvimrc because &t_vb option is reset after vimrc is sourced).

To turn visual bell into beep: `set novisualbell`. I find it more annoying, but it also answers the question: disabling screen blinking.

To turn off visual bell for j/k commands you will have to remap them:

```
noremap <expr> k ((line('.')==1)?'':'k')
noremap <expr> j ((line('.')==line('$'))?'':'j')
```

Answer (score 17):

You can add the line below to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * set vb t_vb= " for your GUI
autocmd VimEnter * set vb t_vb=
```

It will disable both the bell and the visual flash.

Answer (score 12):

A useful command (that also works in the vimrc files) is

`set belloff=all`

This should turn off flashing in all cases, including `esc`.
Requires a recent version of Vim (7.4+)

See other discussion at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524053/423033
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4653/vim-still-flashing-when-it-shouldnt-be

Answer (score 8):

This is counterintuitive, but in order to disable the visual bell completely you have to:

- enable vim's internal visual bell with `set visualbell`
- `set t_vb=`

that is, set the effect of visual bell to empty after enabling it.

If visualbell is not set for you (by default mine wasn't), setting t_vb to empty only will not disable the flashing.