# How to disable Vim bells sounds?

Tags: vim, error-suppression

I am trying to disable the error bells on vim, both visual and audio. However I cannot get them to stay off.

I have the following in my `vimrc`:

```
" Disable annoying beeping
set noerrorbells
set vb t_vb=
```

That doesn't work, I figured some plugin or another setting was resetting it so I added it again to the end of my  `vimrc`, still no luck.

The only way I can get it to turn off is if I manually call `set vb t_vb=` after everything has loaded. I guess I could emulate this by adding a script to the `plugin/after` folder but I am trying to avoid that as it means it's another thing I have to set up whenever I switch to another machine.

You can see my full `vimrc` here: https://github.com/lerp/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: This sound is so annoying. Why is it on by default?? Is there anyone out there who might change that???

Comment: @Soren - The sound depends on your terminal. Back in the day, the terminal bell was pretty innocuous on most terminals. Remember, back when vi started, we used hardware terminals like VT100 and ADM3. (And now you can say "OK Boomer.")

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you have that problem in GVim, adding the following line

```
autocmd GUIEnter * set vb t_vb=
```

in your `if has("gui_running")` conditional block should help.

From `:help 'visualbell'`:

```
Note: When the GUI starts, 't_vb' is reset to its default value.
You might want to set it again in your gvimrc.
```

Comment: Ahh, I must have skipped that line whilst reading the help file, I don't understand why it needs to be reset, it's a bit obnoxious. Thanks for the `autocmd` though.

Comment: [Here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27vb%27) is the link to the vim docs where it is mentioned

Answer (score 171):

Try to use the following line in your .vimrc, .gvimrc files:

```
set belloff=all
```

Comment: Thanks - other answers work for disabling visual bell, but this is the setting that disables audio bell for me.

Comment: Works on vim-gtk3 8.0.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 16LTS after updating the default version of vim with `sudo apt install vim` which installed version 8

Comment: i still get beeps when pressing down arrow on last line in insert mode

Comment: This one produces an error using PowerShell to ssh into RedHat, entered it into ~/.vimrc, and then running vi. So, not viable in vi on RedHat?

Comment: On my (cygwin) installation the file was `~/.vim/vimrc` not `~/.vimrc`.   The RC file locations can be discovered by running `vi --version`.

Comment: Like a hammer to the thumb, that bell is a direct hit my cerebral cortex. *ow*

Comment: Can be shortened to `set bo=all`

Answer (score 14):

For me with gVim it works if I put

```
set noerrorbells
set vb t_vb=
```

in `~/.gvimrc`, not `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 8):

To disable visual bell in **Visual Studio 2019** with **VsVim** extension:

VsVim detects the presence of `_vimrc`, so add the following to it:

**C:\Users\YourName\_vimrc**

```
set vb t_vb=
```

Setting other [options](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Disable_beeping) like `errorbells` or `beloff` had no effect in VsVim.

Comment: I had installed vim extension in pycharm and this solution worked!

Comment: Nothing to do with vsvim or Visual Studio, but this option is the only one given that worked for me -- using PowerShell to ssh into RedHat, and then running vi therein.

Answer (score 5):

After trying all the options mentioned (that haven't worked for me), I figured out the following solution and that worked for me (Windows).
The beep sound is related to the git bash terminal settings.

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the terminal/git bash or whatever you are using.
2. Click on options.
3. Select Terminal.
4. From Bell drop-down select **"no beep"**.

[image]

Comment: Also, you can change the beep into an innocuous sound.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several solutions and different configurations but none worked. GVim resets the visual bell upon starting. The only way it works for me is this snippet at the end of your `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` if you are on Windows):

```
set visualbell t_vb=
if has("autocmd") && has("gui")
    au GUIEnter * set t_vb=
endif
```